# Can this integral be solved?

Tags: real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

I  can't seem to find a way to integrate this function. It is continous and derivable in the real field.

Is this integral actually impossible to evaluate? I couldn't  found it in any manual.

$\int x^x dx $

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's impossible. I recommend checking Wolfram

Comment: Answer is no.  This is well known sadly.

Comment: Have a look at the interesting discussion in (https://www.quora.com/Can-the-integral-displaystyle-int-x-x-mathrm-d-x-be-evaluated?share=1).

Comment: @Simple Art con you tell me where can  I find a proof that this integral can't be evaluated? Or anyway some info about this integral?